# Split Install Error(-5): Split Install API is not available while navigating with Navigation components

Tags: android, kotlin, android-navigation, google-play-core

So I cannot find information about this error anywhere and I've used up the googling (as it has 3 matches). This is my project https://github.com/Nikola-Milovic/Dynamicgram-AndroidApp
I'd usually post my steps and what I've tried, but there are way to many things to type out. I've tried many many solutions, followed the official guides, but nothing has worked for me.

I am navigating both via `findNavController` and via the bottom nav graph (neither work), I use this run configuration

1. Select Run > Edit Configurations from the menu bar. In the left pane
   of the Run/Debug Configurations dialog, select your desired
   configuration under the Android App node.
2. In the dropdown menu next
   to Deploy, select APK from app bundle.
3. Under Dynamic features to deploy, check the box next to each dynamic feature module, if any,
   you want to include when deploying your app. Click OK.

If anyone can clone and check out the app, or provide some detail as to what is happening with the error I am getting

```
I/PlayCore: UID: [10087]  PID: [29410] SplitInstallService : ServiceConnectionImpl.onServiceConnected(ComponentInfo{com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.splitinstallservice.SplitInstallService})
I/PlayCore: UID: [10087]  PID: [29410] SplitInstallService : linkToDeath
I/PlayCore: UID: [10087]  PID: [29410] SplitInstallService : Unbind from service.
I/PlayCore: UID: [10087]  PID: [29410] SplitInstallService : onError(-5)
I/DynamicInstallManager: Error requesting install of feature_explore: Split Install Error(-5): Split Install API is not available. (https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/play/core/splitinstall/model/SplitInstallErrorCode.html#API_NOT_AVAILABLE)
W/DefaultProgressFragment: Installation failed with error -5
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `bundletool` to build build your app and create split apk's.